# Error In R code in LPPL model in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls, non-linear-regression

I am learning R and had problem when I try run LPPL using nls. I used monthly data of KLSE.

```
> library(tseries)

> library(zoo)

ts<-read.table(file.choose(),header=TRUE)

ts

  rdate      Close      Date

1    8/1998  302.91     0
2    9/1998  373.52   100
3   10/1998  405.33   200
4   11/1998  501.47   300
5   12/1998  586.13   400
6    1/1999  591.43   500
7    2/1999  542.23   600
8    3/1999  502.82   700
9    4/1999  674.96   800
10   5/1999  743.04   900
11   6/1999  811.10  1000
12   7/1999  768.69  1100
13   8/1999  767.06  1200
14   9/1999  675.45  1300
15  10/1999  742.87  1400
16  11/1999  734.66  1500
17  12/1999  812.33  1600
18   1/2000  922.10  1700
19   2/2000  982.24  1800
20   3/2000  974.38  1900
21   4/2000  898.35  2000
22   5/2000  911.51  2100
23   6/2000  833.37  2200
24   7/2000  798.83  2300
25   8/2000  795.84  2400
26   9/2000  713.51  2500
27  10/2000  752.36  2600
28  11/2000  729.95  2700
29  12/2000  679.64  2800
30   1/2001  727.73  2900
31   2/2001  709.39  3000
32   3/2001  647.48  3100
33   4/2001  584.50  3200
34   5/2001  572.88  3300
35   6/2001  592.99  3400
36   7/2001  659.40  3500
37   8/2001  687.16  3600
38   9/2001  615.34  3700
39  10/2001  600.07  3800
40  11/2001  638.02  3900
41  12/2001  696.09  4000
42   1/2002  718.82  4100
43   2/2002  708.91  4200
44   3/2002  756.10  4300
45   4/2002  793.99  4400
46   5/2002  741.76  4500
47   6/2002  725.44  4600
48   7/2002  721.59  4700
49   8/2002  711.36  4800
50   9/2002  638.01  4900
51  10/2002  659.57  5000
52  11/2002  629.22  5100
53  12/2002  646.32  5200
54   1/2003  664.77  5300
55   2/2003  646.80  5400
56   3/2003  635.72  5500
57   4/2003  630.37  5600
58   5/2003  671.46  5700
59   6/2003  691.96  5800
60   7/2003  720.56  5900
61   8/2003  743.30  6000
62   9/2003  733.45  6100
63  10/2003  817.12  6200
64  11/2003  779.28  6300
65  12/2003  793.94  6400
66   1/2004  818.94  6500
67   2/2004  879.24  6600
68   3/2004  901.85  6700
69   4/2004  838.21  6800
70   5/2004  810.67  6900
71   6/2004  819.86  7000
72   7/2004  833.98  7100
73   8/2004  827.98  7200
74   9/2004  849.96  7300
75  10/2004  861.14  7400
76  11/2004  917.19  7500
77  12/2004  907.43  7600
78   1/2005  916.27  7700
79   2/2005  907.38  7800
80   3/2005  871.35  7900
81   4/2005  878.96  8000
82   5/2005  860.73  8100
83   6/2005  888.32  8200
84   7/2005  937.39  8300
85   8/2005  913.56  8400
86   9/2005  927.54  8500
87  10/2005  910.76  8600
88  11/2005  896.13  8700
89  12/2005  899.79  8800
90   1/2006  914.01  8900
91   2/2006  928.94  9000
92   3/2006  926.63  9100
93   4/2006  949.23  9200
94   5/2006  927.78  9300
95   6/2006  914.69  9400
96   7/2006  935.85  9500
97   8/2006  958.12  9600
98   9/2006  967.55  9700
99  10/2006  988.30  9800
100 11/2006 1080.66  9900
101 12/2006 1096.24 10000
102  1/2007 1189.35 10100
103  2/2007 1196.45 10200
104  3/2007 1246.87 10300
105  4/2007 1322.25 10400
106  5/2007 1346.89 10500
107  6/2007 1354.38 10600
108  7/2007 1373.71 10700
109  8/2007 1273.93 10800
110  9/2007 1336.30 10900
111 10/2007 1413.65 11000
112 11/2007 1396.98 11100
113 12/2007 1445.03 11200

df <- data.frame(ts)

df <- data.frame(Date=df$Date,Y=df$Close)

df <- df[!is.na(df$Y),]

library(minpack.lm)
library(ggplot2)

f <- function(pars, xx){pars$a+pars$b*(pars$tc-xx)^pars$m*   (1+pars$c*cos(pars$omega*log(pars$tc-xx)+pars$phi))}

resids <- function(p,observed,xx){df$Y-f(p,xx)}

nls.out<-nls.lm(par=list(a=7.048293, b=-8.8e-5, tc=112000, m=0.5, omega=3.03, phi=-9.76, c=-14), fn=resids, observed=df$Y, xx=df$days, control=nls.lm.control(maxiter=1024, ftol=1e-6, maxfev=1e6))

par <- nls.out$par

nls.final<-nls(Y~a+(tc-days)^m*(b+c*cos(omega*log(tc-days)+phi)), data=df, start=par, algorithm="plinear", control=nls.control(maxiter=1024, minFactor=1e-8))
```

> Error in qr.solve(QR.B, cc) : singular matrix 'a' in solve

I got error a singular matrix.What I need to change to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: the cosine term is zero for some value, this makes the matrix singular, you basically need to constrict the parameter space.  Additionally, I would read more of the literature since some fancy trig work will remove the phi parameter, this improves the nl optimization enough to get useful and reproducible results.

Comment: you need to add bounds to the phi term as cos(x)=0 for some x, this makes the matrix singular, i.e. R cannot invert it